# How to set date for inline bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I've tried using

`$("#datetimepicker1").data("DateTimePicker").date('2017/04/23 23:34:23');`

Then I got error cannot read property date of undefined.

Is there another way to set date and time?

Comment: Yes it works normally. But when I use some other plugins. I got the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working snippet:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    inline: true,
    sideBySide: true
});


$("#datetimepicker1").data("DateTimePicker").date('2017/04/23 23:34:23');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=1"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/5a991bff/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="datetimepicker1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: snippet is not working, ` "message": "TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 25,
  "colno": 31`